# Project Research - Zoomable, Scrollable, Hoverable High-Resolution Images

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

I'm doing some research before I start a project, and I want to know what the best method of going about this project is before I begin. Any help I can get would be much appreciated, and I'd be happy to provide more information if necessary.

Basically, I'll be given a number of extremely high resolution images to display to users. I want to create an interface whereby the user can scroll around the image and zoom in, as well as hover over parts of the picture and receive some information about that specific location. Also, I would really, really like it if I could do it without using Flash in any way, both because I don't like Flash and because it wouldn't work on i-devices.

Here's an example of the [zooming capability](http://www.kennicottbible.org/all.php) that I'm looking for, and here's an example of the [hover capability](http://dss.collections.imj.org.il/isaiah) that I'm looking for (sorry they're both biblical manuscripts, don't mean to get religious on y'all, these were the best examples I could find!)

Anyway, so far I've found [this spiffy script](http://www.ajax-zoom.com/) for zooming, but I haven't found anything for hovering yet (another example of what I'm looking for is something like when you tag someone in a picture on Facebook - if you hover over their face, their name pops up). And to make things all the more difficult, I have to figure out how to make them play nice, so zooming in doesn't break the hovering capabilities.

So my questions are...does anyone have any experience with anything like this? Do you have any suggestions for projects (open source is far preferred) that allow for this kind of thing? I'd really appreciate any help you fine people can give me! I'll be publishing my findings and code afterwards.

Comment: How do you plan to implement hover interaction on iDevices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the technology behind Google Maps (and other such technology) would be the way to go. With Google Maps API you can use your own custom tiles instead of the map tiles. You could then set boundaries on the map to stop the user navigating away from your available imagery. Lastly, you can use the API to specify the coordinates for polygons on the "map". These polygons are great as the allow you to have hover/click events which should provide you the functionality you're after.

A good article I found on something similar to what you're after can be found here: http://forevermore.net/articles/photo-zoom/

Hope this provides some direction and sounds like a fun project that you're about to embark on :)